# Powershell [WMI] type methods

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, wmi

using WMI with PowerShell I found something I don't understand:

```
gwmi -class MIIS_ManagementAgent -namespace "root/MicrosoftIdentityIntegrationServer" | foreach 
    If ($_.Name -eq "contoso.com") {
        $foo= $_

    }
    else {
        $boo= $_
    }
}
$state= $foo.ResumeState("FullSync")
$res = $foo.execute("FullSync") 
$details = $foo.RunDetails()
$RunStatus = $foo.RunStatus()
```

I know that `$foo` contains [WMI] type accelerator but I cannot find any documentation of what are the methods of this type. I have no idea what `ResumeState`, `execute`, `RunDetails` and `RunStatus` methods are doing. I want to transfer this calls to C# but I have to understand what those calls are.

Comment: If that code is correct, they are methods on the MIIS_ManagementAgent class, that the WMI query returns.

Comment: [What @gnud said](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms697764(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @gnud Thank you for the answer. I have checked MSDN webpage for the method but nowhere I can find `ResumeState` method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms697768(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: There seems to be some Sharepoint WMI method called ResumeState, but that's all I can find: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj575409(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: have you tried piping it and getting the member of it . 
$foo | Get-Member -MemberType method